# systemu - execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, background-process

I am running systemu from within a delayed_job process. I had a job fail, and found this error in my delayed_jobs table:

```
execution expired
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:76:in `close'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:76:in `popen'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in systemu'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:168:in `quietly'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:75:in `block in systemu'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:236:in `block in tmpdir'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:221:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:221:in `tmpdir'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:68:in `systemu'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/systemu-2.5.0/lib/systemu.rb:10:in `systemu'
```

It was working fine before, but this is a larger job I'm running. Is there some timeout that I need to set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the problem was that the delayed_job timed out. I had to up the time limit with:

```
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 48.hours #2 days
```

in app/config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb